# How did 'the trickster' know Sam and Dean were in town?

Tags: supernatural

So in season 5, episode 8 of supernatural we find out something about The Trickster...

> Believe it or not, he's the Archangel Gabriel

So I was wondering, how did he know Sam and Dean were 'in town'? Did he lure them to that town then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The opening of the episode shows that Sam and Dean actually tracked the Trickster to the town, and not the other way around.

They were investigating a case where a woman claims her husband was murdered by "The Incredible Hulk", and figure out that it's The Trickster behind the deaths. Once they start to chase him down, it would have been easy enough for him to figure out that they were asking questions in town, etc.

Given who we learn The Trickster is, and how he's related to the Season 5 plot, it seems very likely that this was actually a trap set for the brothers. He must have expected them to hear about such a bizarre murder and come to investigate, where he had the trap planned out. (Presumably, if another hunter had shown up, The Trickster would just have moved to another town and tried again.)

Comment: I had forgotten, thinking the Hulk thing was another episode. This is the correct answer, of course, and better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

He is one of the most powerful beings in the universe, as near as I can tell. At the top, we have God and Death. Below them are the leviathans. And below (equal to?) them the archangels, of which only four have ever been portrayed. While still weaker than both Michael and Lucifer, it should not be forgotten that Gabriel is a being that could single-handedly wipe out all of the pagan deities. Probably without breaking a sweat.

Though Sam and Dean are hidden from the angels' limited omniscience via the rib sigils, Gabriel and other angels can see both of them if they happen to focus their presence on a particular region (Castiel once searched an entire town for a trumpet in just a few seconds). Gabriel's not dumb either, by any stretch of the imagination, and luring and/or following them wouldn't be tough.

Comment: I've not gotten to the bit about leviathans yet, season 7 right? Whilst I'm not certain the sigils don't protect against sufficiently powerful angels, I do agree on Gabriel being powerful enough to trick them into turning up.

Comment: @John The sigils on Sam and Dean are specifically there to keep them hidden from *Michael* and *Lucifer*, the only two angels that are more powerful than Gabriel, so presumably he can't see past them either. The only time the angels seem able to find the two is when they "pray" for them, as they do for Castiel in later seasons.

Comment: I believe Metatron is above the Archangels, but I'm not completely certain.

Comment: Metatron has never been introduced into the show's mythology, and it seems likely that they'll do so at this point.

Comment: Metatron actually has been introduced into the show's mythology, despite never making an entrance as a character. He/She/It transcribed God's word, and one bit of those works made its entrance in form of a stone.

That being said, I think Death probably ranks higher than God - if memory serves me right, he states that he was there before God, and will at some point end God.

Comment: I did not hear Metatron's name mentioned. As for Death, he says that "neither of them remember who is older". He seems fairly confident that he will reap God, but reluctant as if it really were a big deal... so it's not clear that he is more powerful. They certainly both belong in the same category even if ranked unequally. It seemed an afterthought for him to alter *astronomy* at one point, after all.